# Azure AD -Single Sign On with personal account

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have got an application registered on Azure portal which I can use to Single Sign on with my company email account. But it doesn't work if I use personal Microsoft account. Is it possible to enable single sign on for personal microsoft accounts? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apps created on portal.azure.com connect to the Azure AD v1 endpoint, which works with organizational users (and guests of organizations) exclusively. 
If your app needs to work with both work&school accounts and personal accounts, please consider integrating with the Azure AD v2 endpoint. More info at http://aka.ms/aaddevv2

Comment: I have now registered an app on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. Now when I try to sign in with personal account  I get following error: "User account ..@outlook.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'company.Ltd' and cannot access the application 'clientid_value' in that tenant."

Comment: How did you sign in apps.dev.microsoft.com? That determines where the app gets created. Also, I would recommend you start a different question and provide more details (like exact creation details, exact error text, etc)

Answer (score 6):

Are you only looking to be able to sign onto the account, or are you requiring admin access for the Microsoft account?

If you are just looking to sign on, using the Microsoft account should not be an issue. If you have not done so already, you need to add the user accounts (and Microsoft email) to the tenant. This is under Active Directory > Enterprise Applications > Click into the application > Users and Groups > + Add User > + Invite. You need to specifically invite these users as guest users who can log into the application.

This documentation explains where to do this: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect